# Can you mix .NET Standard 2.0 & 2.1 in a project?

Tags: .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

Is it possible for Project to reference other projects that are a mixture of .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.1?

I have a utility class library based on Standard 2.0 that is used by both a.NET5 and .NET4.8 websites/applications.

In one of my applications, I want to use .NET Standard 2.1 but it complains that my utility class library is .NET Standard 2.0.

All my code is related to the same project so runs in the same Solution.

Comment: It should be fine - please post a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: In one of my personal projects, I have a netstandard 1.0 library that is consumed without complaints by a netstandard 2.0 project - higher netstandard versions extend the lower versions.

Comment: What is that complaint exactly? When/where do you see it, what is the exact text (minus personal info, if any)?